# How to set up French Language for Google Assistant SDK on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: google-assistant-sdk

How to set up French Language for Google Assistant SDK on a Raspberry Pi

Will we have the voice in French?

Thks

Regards

Anne Romane

Answer (score 1):

French is not (yet) supported. Stay tuned for it to be available this summer or later this year.